# how to run particular http request to multiple times in jmeter?

Tags: csv, jmeter

I've multiple http samples in Test Plan but i want to run only one request for multiple times based on csv data set config and remaining http requests will run once particular sample is complete all the iteration based on csv data set config.
[image]

In above image i've 5 http samples and i've csv data set for first request,once first request is run for entire csv data set test data then another samples should run,please provide solution how to perform this type of operation in jmeter.

Answer (score 5):

you can use Loop Control and provide the number of hits you needed.

- To go to Loop Control:
- Right click on the Thread/ThreadGroup
- Click on Add
- select the Logic controller
- Select the Loop Controller

Answer (score 2):

According to the problem, there is a need to execute a particular request to execute in a loop. The loop could be organized in the following way.

```
 -> Thread Group 
   -> Loop Controller 
       -->Particular Request 
   -> Other Request
```

[image]

The CSV Dataset could be found in Config Element and should contain a path to a particular file with data (e.g. accounts.csv).

Both elements could be located in 
Loop controller: Add ->Logic Controller -> Loop Controller
CSV Data Set : Add -> Config Elements -> CSV Data Set Config.

The loop can run for the exact amount of records in a file if 
Loop Count is equal to a number of strings in the accounts.csv
Forever, it could be stopped by Test Duration automatically or by Stop button.

The CSV Data Set config should have a path to a file with data. 
If a file contains headers, then Variables will be assigned based on column names from first string, otherwise, it is necessary to provide variables names in configuration.

[image]

ANSWER: If you use 9 variables and all of them are set as header names in a file, then don't provide them in CSV Data Set Config. They will be created automatically, so you can use all 9 variables through names in your file. 
If headers are not provided, set 9 all in a Variable Names field, using comma as separator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) like:

   - Reference name: `foo`
   - Recycle on EOF: `false`
   - Stop thread on EOF: `false`
2. Put the CSV Data Set Config under the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and put `${__javaScript("${foo}" != "<EOF>",)}` into "Condition" input
3. Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) under the While Controller and put `"${foo}" != "<EOF>"` into the "Condition" input
4. Put your **first request** as a child of the If Controller

   Replace `foo` with your actual JMeter Variable reference name everywhere in the script.

This way JMeter will loop until there are entries in the CSV file and will proceed with the remaining requests when the end of CSV file will be reached.

See **Reading all Values from the CSV and Continue** chapter of the [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more detailed information on configuring JMeter for your scenario.

Comment: I'm not able to find reference Name as you mentioned in any of below controller , 1.While Controller 2.If Controller.as well as Csv data set Config.Please suggest where to add Reference Name

Comment: I'm using 9 different variables to pass data from csv file,how can i do this for 9 variables

Answer (score 0):

You can verify with only one variable and Rest variable you don't required in If and while controller.